# How do I change the local path of a language in Django?

Tags: django, internationalization, locale

I have a web set up with 3 languages (['es', 'en', 'it']) ​​in Angular that works with the Django server.
Django by default has the English local path defined as **/en**,  I want the url of the English configuration to be **'/us'** (by default it is '/ en'), I just want to change it for English, for 'es' or 'it' as it comes by default is fine.
I want the URL to look like this `myurl.com/us` in English, how would you recommend me to make this change?

The structure is the following:

```
-apps
--webapp
---templates
----webapp
-----en (inside index.html)
-----es (inside index.html)
-----it (inside index.html)
-conf
--settings.py
-middleware
--locale.py

conf.settings.py have this language configuration
LANGUAGES = (
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('it', _('Italian')),
    ('en', _('English')),
)
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
LANGUAGE_CODES = [language[0] for language in LANGUAGES]
```

Additionally I have configured a middleware to recognize the user's location and place the corresponding language code in the URL

```
from django.conf import settings
from .utils.geolocation import get_language_by_ip
cookie_name = settings.LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME
class LocalizationMiddleware(object):

    def get_language_cookie(self, request):
        return request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name)

    def set_language_cookie(self, request, value):
        request.COOKIES[cookie_name] = value

    def get_i18n_url_language(self, request):
        url = request.path.split('/')
        if len(url) > 1 and len(url[1].split('-')[0]) == 2:
            return url[1]
        return None

    def process_request(self, request):
        language = self.get_i18n_url_language(request)
        if language is not None and language not in settings.LANGUAGE_CODES:
            return
        if language is None:
            language = self.get_language_cookie(request)
        if language is None:
            language = get_language_by_ip(request)
        if language is None:
            language = settings.LANGUAGE_CODE
        self.set_language_cookie(request, language)
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response.set_cookie(cookie_name, request.COOKIES.get(cookie_name, settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))
        return response
```

This all works fine, however I want the url for the English language to change from .../en to .../us

Comment: hi, you change `/en` to `/us`/ or `/es` ?

Comment: @MaximeK 
I want the url of the English configuration to be '/ us' (by default it is '/ en'), I just want to change it for English, for 'es' or 'it' as it comes by default is fine.

Comment: replacing `('en', _('English')),` by `('us', _('English')),` is not working ?

Comment: @Maximek that doesn't work, because 'us' is not the code of a language, what I want is to keep the language setting as 'en' but the URL to be 'us', I don't know if a redirect should be done ( I wouldn't know how to do it either)